# foreach loop through first item in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, file-upload, foreach

I want to loop through files and always make sure its just one item in the array I am looping through

```
var files = Request.Form.Files;
var singleFile = files[0];
foreach (var file in singleFile)
{

}
```

I am getting the error foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

How can I fix this ! Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to iterate single item? `singleFile` already contains first item of the array.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "looping through"? How can you loop through a single item?

Comment: I just want to make sure that it is always getting the first item in the loop as people may upload 2 files at the same time if that makes sense

Comment: `files[0]` will always get the first item in the collection. If that's all you want you're done. You can't iterate _that item_ because it is an item, not a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't loop through an item that is not a collection type. You have assigned the first file in [`Request.Form.Files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx) to a variable. So this variable references a single file not all.

You can use the [`Count`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.count(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [`HttpFileCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int fileCount = Request.Form.Files.Count;
if(fileCount > 0)
{
    HttpPostedFile firstFile = Request.Form.Files[0];
    // do something with it ....
}
```

If you want to enumerate all you can use a loop but on `Request.Form.Files`:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Form.Files)
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear. `singleItem` is just *one single item* from your original collection, not the actual collection. If you want to check, that the collection has only one element, use `files.Count`:

```
if(files.Count != 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Evil, evil");
else
{
    var singleFile = files[0];
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will give the first item of collection.  if the collection count is 0, then it will return `null`.

```
Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Since `Request.Form.Files` is not an array but a `HttpFileCollection` which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` this won't compile